# In The Good Place, how long in Earth years is one Jeremy Bearimy?

Tags: the-good-place

In The Good Place, we are told that time in the afterlife works along the Jeremy Bearimy pattern. At the end of the final season, repeated references are made to the passage of time in terms of numbers of Bearimies.

But a Bearimy nonetheless appears to be a discrete amount of duration with reference to earth time (something like 3:1 or 300:1 from what I can see). Is that a set amount, which is known?

Edit: to clarify (I hope), how many subjective years does a person experience while within one entire Jeremy Bearimy?

Comment: IIRC, the cursive Jeremy Bearimy signature was meant to suggest that time in the afterlife is not linear with respect to Earth time, and would at various points curve back on itself. That's what allowed for Eleanor et al to revisit their pasts in one episode and precludes any sort of simple scale factor. The "x Jeremy Bearimys later" scene cards shown in the finale only indicate an apparent sequence of events and their relative proximity in "afterlife" time.

Comment: @AnthonyX right, but that refers to direction while this question is about duration, if that makes sense. How long in earth years does it take to complete one Jeremy Bearimy?

Comment: One way to look at it: Jeremy Bearimy is a closed figure; by the time you've completed one Jeremy Bearimy you're back where you started, so no Earth time has elapsed. The whole point is that time in the afterlife is not comparable in any way to Earth time. From a production/writing perspective, it's an invention to avoid linking "passage of time" in the afterlife to passage of time on Earth and allow for storylines which included the many hundreds of "good place" reboots and visits to the past.

Comment: I think the question really comes down to is what is the approximation of how many years does a person experience over the course of a Jeremy bearimy. For comparison, how does a person estimate; especially in the final episodes, how long it took the characters to realize that they are tired of experiencing that which is basically a Life after Life, you know the afterlife, not in a way that represents getting tired of it all but just realizing you've done everything that you could ever have imagined doing.

Comment: I suspect the unit was deliberately used to handwave away ideas of the *absolute* passage of time, which (one would suspect) would have a very different subjective feel to the effectively immortal, in favor of suggesting *relative* time periods. That is, one Jeremy Bearimy feels like... a while, and three Jeremy Bearimys (Jeremys Bearimy?) feels *much longer*, and the characters wouldn't be inclined to compare those periods to "interval between my birthdays when I was alive". But I don't have any canon to back this up.

Answer (score 1):

As described by Michael in Season 3 Episode 4, one Jeremy Bearimy in earth DAYS would be 36,259 days. Meaning One Jeremy Bearimy in earth YEARS would be 99.27 years.

Comment: This would be a better answer with support -- a quote from the source or reference, perhaps -- for why you believe this is the case.

Comment: @ZeissIkon there you go